# Selecting a face in a script so that you can edit eg resize it?

Tags: mesh, scripting, bmesh

I was trying to write a script to generate an object from primitives but came across a problem I couldn't solve.  The code generates a cylinder and finds the face as well as putting it into edit mode.  However when I try and select it in edit mode the whole object is still selected.
How do I script the selection of just that face?
When I do it by hand the selection of the face which I can do generates nothing in the info window.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=2)
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder']
ob.name = 'NewCylinder'
mesh = ob.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
n = 0
for face in mesh.polygons:
    face.select = False
    if len(face.vertices) > 4:
        print(' end face {}'.format(n))
        n += 1
        if n == 2:
            face.select = True
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.33, 0.33, 0.33))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might seem counter-intuitive, but you need to be in Object mode to change the selection when using `.mesh`.  I changed a few more things, like you can use the `'DESELECT'` action in `mesh.select_all` else edges are still selected when you try to un-select faces

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=2, enter_editmode=True)
ob = bpy.context.object  # gets a reference to the newly created object 
ob.name = 'NewCylinder'
mesh = ob.data

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
n = 0
for face in mesh.polygons:
    if len(face.vertices) > 4:
        n += 1
        if n == 2:
            face.select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.33, 0.33, 0.33))
```

[image]

Comment: Noteworthy: `bpy.context.object` should be used after calling a mesh primitive operator to refer to the newly created object (like zeffii did). You might pick the wrong object otherwise if the name already existed.

Comment: @CoDEmanX i'll add that as a comment into the code too

Comment: (Sorry for the comment but @zeffi I am delighted with the solution and stackexchange.  I racked my head about this for 1 day)

Comment: @hum3, as you can see by the other answer there's a variety of approaches to this. My preference is the `bmesh` method shown by CoDEmanX, but I wanted to provide an answer that shared more with your original question - to keep the point of reference.

Comment: @zeffi  I know that I  ought to learn the bmesh route but I am just starting and this matched using the info window like a macro recorder.

Comment: When editing faces you should select face mode `bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (False, False, True)` otherwise you will be selecting faces via vertexes, which can lead to problems. In this example, if you remove `if n == 2:` you would simply be selecting all the faces.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this with [Bmesh module](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bmesh.html), which does not require mode switches:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

scene = bpy.context.scene

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, cap_ends=True, segments=32, diameter1=1, diameter2=1, depth=2)

caps = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) > 4]
bottom_cap = min(caps, key=lambda f: f.verts[0].co.z)

mat = Matrix.Identity(4)
mat[0][0] = 1/3
mat[1][1] = 1/3
mat[2][2] = 1
bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=mat, verts=bottom_cap.verts)

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cylinder")
bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()

ob = bpy.data.objects.new("NewCylinder", me)
ob.location = scene.cursor_location
scene.objects.link(ob)
scene.update()
```

BTW: The same result (with bottom face scaled down by 1/3) can also be achieved with a single call to `create_cone()`:

```
# diameter1 controls the size of the bottom cap
bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, cap_ends=True, segments=32, diameter1=1/3, diameter2=1, depth=2)
```